# How to convert savedmodel to checkpoint(tensorflow2.3.0)

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensor

I am using tensorflow2.3.0.

And I have savedmodel.

I want to retrain this model, so I think I should convert the savedmodel to checkpoint.

How can I?

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__ -> 2.3.0
```

Comment: Please take a look at: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load